# Hacking with the last four of your SSN

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose a hacker gets a hold of the last four numbers of your social security number (the serial number).  What is the probability that the hacker randomly guesses your full social security number?

k=5
n=10

P(A)= 1/10^5 = .000001 = .0001%

Is this the right way to go about the solution?

Comment: looks right to me.

Comment: I think you have an extra 0 in your decimal, though.

Comment: In reality a hacker(?) might be more likely to guess correctly than this, since the leading digits of the SSN are not randomly distributed.

Comment: I think you are right, one extra zero.

Answer (score 2):

Why guess randomly? First off, your first three digits are nearly uniquely determined by your [state of birth](http://www.mrfa.org/ssn.htm). This information is not hard to deduce, as most people's current state is also their state of birth. The [group numbers](http://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/ssb/v69n2/v69n2p55.html) are generated not consecutively, but in a defined order based on birthdate, so if you can get an estimate of the time of birth, you can narrow your choices down to two or three group numbers. So if you can get birthyear down to $\pm 5$ years (corresponding to 5 or 10 group numbers), and their state of birth, you can guess their SSN easily. That'd be believable in a "oh sorry I forgot--it's this number instead" way.

Note that post-2011, SSN's are in fact assigned randomly, so it's much harder to steal a three-year old's bank account number via their SSN.

Comment: Not a maths answer, but nevertheless true. In fact many privacy experts have long complained about this (ultimately prompting the change). It's even easier for some folks to deduce the full SSN, as they also have access to DOB and sometimes location of birth. I can't even call my cable company to complain about poor service without giving them some or all of those data.